# c++ parsing input string(with special symbols) to vector variables

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, stringstream

I want to do this:

I have created

```
vector<string> inputStates;
vector<string> finalStates;
```

I want to get the values of inputStates and finalStates by parsing the following two lines. They are read from a .txt file using `getline()`. How should I write the codes? Thank you.

```
Initial State:  1
Final States:   {3,14,20,29,30}
```

The result should be

```
inputStates={"1"};
finalStates = {"3","14","20","29","30"}.
```

I think I should get element and then use finalStates.push_back() to append. But I really don't know how to get the elements from the strings.

Comment: vector<string> final stages = {"3", "14", "20", "29"};

Do you need to do this?

Comment: What is initial state: 1 supposed to be? Same with the one below that? Are they user input strings? or what?

Comment: Yes @AmithChinthaka.

Comment: @xElsa, they are from a .txt file

Comment: So I think you have the answer :)

Comment: You can use sprintf to convert numbers in strings to real numbers. Check this out. Maybe this will be usefull.

Comment: @AmithChinthaka No I don't I don't know how to separate the elements from the strings.

Comment: Just use stringstream and do ss << 45; and ss.str() to get 45 as string then do push_back to the vector

Comment: Sorry I meant those two lines are from a .txt file and I use getline() to get them. How should I separate the elements from them?

Comment: Oddly enough, getline again. put the line you read into a std::stringstream  `std::stringstream linestream(line);` and then use `std::getline(linestream, token, '{')` to get everything up to the { and throw it out. Then `std::getline(linestream, token, '}')`  to get everything inside the {}. Keep that and put it in yet another stringstream. Then `while std::getline(yetanotherstringstream, number,  ','))` and put the numbers into a vector.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include an "fstream" to read the data from the text file and then create an input stream (ifstream)

```
#include <fstream>

ifstream myFile;
```

and then use the myFile stream to open your text file and read from it.
More information can be found here.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

When you read the string using the ifstream you can read it one word at a time and then push the appropriate numbers into your vector.